# Oracle DB Query Issue : Same query different behaviour

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, type-conversion

Below is my Query. In one Oracle DB (11.2.3.0) this is giving me error but in other same Oracle DB below query is working fine. Not able to understand this different behavior.

Output from one DB

```
SQL> select id  from cag where greeting_id=1111100001 for update;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Output from other DB

```
SQL> select id from cag where greeting_id=1111100001 for update;

ID - 9111100001
```

Is there any DB internal setting?

Comment: What is the data type of the `greeting_id` column? It looks like you're storing the ID as a string, and some of the values don't represent numbers. If they are supposed to always be numbers the, store them as numbers. Always use the right data type.

Comment: this is the datatype : GREETING_ID                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)

Comment: In one DB query is working fine but in other DB, same query is giving me error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing numbers in a `varchar2` column. That is not good practice, for many reasons including performance, but particularly because it causes data issues like this.

If the column is only ever supposed to contain numbers then make it an actual number column.

If it is a general column that is expected to hold numeric and other data then you should really reconsider the design anyway and put the different types of data in separate columns of the right type. It *looks* like it's expected to always be a number though - you wouldn't expect an ID to have a varying type.

In the meantime, to query a string column you need to avoid implicit conversion. At the moment when you do:

```
select id  from cag where greeting_id=1111100001;
```

the database has to convert every string in the `greeting_id` column into a number before comparing it with `1111100001`, and it is that implicit conversion from string to number that is throwing the error - because you have values in the column that cannot be implicitly converted. In one database all the column values can be converted; on the other at least one value cannot. If you aren't expecting that then look at the data to see if someone has stored something unexpected like 'none' or 'invalid' or 'unknown', or even a decimal fraction with the wrong decimal separator.

If you have to stick with a string when look for a string - compare column data with values and literals of the same type:

```
select id  from cag where greeting_id='1111100001';
```

The correct approach is to make the column the correct data type though.

Comment: ....ok at the data to see if someone has stored something unexpected like 'none' or 'invalid' or 'unknown', or even a decimal fraction with the wrong decimal separator.....This helps me. Someone stored wrong data...Thanks Alex

Comment: @VJS - if the data type was NUMBER they wouldn't be *able* to store invalid data.

Comment: Its a legacy thing. I ll check now and update the datatype accordingly. Thanks a lot for your help. Its very nice and straight forward answer.